# I am not able to read mail content

Tags: java

I have a outlook where I have to read subject and body content of the mail in java. Everything works fine, but if I have body with screenshot it throws ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

I have tried to put the mail as a doc attachment. But no use.

```java
String destFilePath = path + ticketId + "/" + bpFileName;
File f = new File(path + ticketId);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
InputStream input = bp.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytRead = -1;
byte[] byteRead = new byte[4096];

while ((bytRead = input.read(byteRead)) != -1) {
    if (byteRead != null) {
        String content2 = new String(byteRead, "us-ascii");
        if (content2 != null) {
            content = content.concat(content2);
        }
    }
}
input.close();
```

Expected is text or html content. But it gives xml,html,text, invalid byte sequence exception.

Comment: Without having some example input data it is difficult to say with any certainty what the problem is, but I have a feeling from what you say that you are trying to turn image data into a string.

Comment: Definitely unrelated to the error, but this line looks wrong `if (byteRead != null) {` because `byteRead` will never be `null`.